# How to find the master URL for an existing spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark

Currently I am running my program as

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("Test Data Analysis")
  .setMaster("local[*]")
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "32g")
  .set("spark.driver.memory", "32g")
  .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "4g")
```

Even though I am running on a cluster of 5 machines (each with 376 GB Physical RAM). my program errors out with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

My data sizes are big... but not so big that they exceed 32 GB Executor memory * 5 nodes.

I suspect it may be because I am using "local" as my master. I have seen documentation say use `spark://machinename:7070`

However I want to know for my cluster... how do I determine this URL and port

EDIT: I can see that the documentation talks about running something called "spark-master.sh" in order to make a node as master.

in my case the spark cluster was setup/maintained by someone else and so I don't want to change topology by starting my own master.

How can I query and find out which node is the existing master.

I already tried picking up a random node in the cluster and then try 'spark://node:7077' but this does not work and gives error

```
[15/11/03 20:06:21 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to
 akka.tcp://sparkMaster@node:7077: 
akka.remote.EndpointAssociationException: Association failed with 
[akka.tcp://sparkMaster@node:7077]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found that doing `--master yarn-cluster` works best. this makes sure that spark uses all the nodes of the hadoop cluster.

Comment: How/Where do you append these lines ? Inside the command setMaster() ?

Comment: Cant understand how to set the master URL , Considering this as a remote client. Should not we have to supply IP/Port ? If so how to find this url ?

Comment: Where do you physically type this? In hdfs, in bash?

Comment: @math_law he means passing it as an option. See [this URL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/running-on-yarn.html) for examples. You can also do `.setMaster("yarn-cluster")`.

Answer (score 12):

You are on the spot. `.setMaster("local[*]")` will run spark in self-contained mode. In this mode spark can utilize only the resources of the local machine.

If you've already set up a spark cluster on top of your physical cluster. The solution is an easy one, Check `http://master:8088` where master is pointing to spark master machine. There you can see spark master URI, and by default is `spark://master:7077`, actually quite a bit of information lives there, if you have a spark standalone cluster.

However, I see a lot of questions on SO claiming this does not work with many different reasons. Using `spark-submit` utility is just less error prone, [See usage](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).

But if you haven't got a spark cluster yet I suggest setting up a [Spark Standalone cluster first](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html).

Comment: I did replace master with a name of a node in my cluster. but still same problem. if I do `http://<machinename>:8088` it returns nothing in browser. I am using spark-submit but I think it uses local as master by default.

Comment: with `spark-submit` remove `.setMaster("local[*]")` from spark app,  and pass `--master spark://master:7077` to `spark-submit`. It is all documented in the link given above.

Answer (score 2):

use the command to get the URL information **sc.uiWebUrl**

Comment: This worked but you need to add in the extended answer.

Answer (score 0):

To view the master Node in spark DSE(Datastax) using shell

```
dse client-tool spark leader-address
```